# Conneted to wlan0, but have no internet

Tags: wireless, networking, gateway, ip-address

I have a problem that only occurs on my home network. If I log on to Ubuntu, I get a wifi connection, I have an IP-address, everything looks right, but I have no internet connection.

I can use the internet on the same laptop running Windows, and I can use other wireless networks (work, school) on Ubuntu. Only the home network somehow doesn't work. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 32-bit.

Here is my route -n and ifconfig:

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

    0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0

    192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:ae:c5:a1:33:c0  

      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

      Interrupt:48 


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  

      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host

      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1

      RX packets:1739126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

      TX packets:1739126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 

      RX bytes:170808116 (170.8 MB)  TX bytes:170808116 (170.8 MB)

wlan0     
    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5d:60:9d:41:13  

    inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

    inet6 addr: fe80::4a5d:60ff:fe9d:4113/64 Scope:Link

    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

    RX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

    TX packets:3669 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

    RX bytes:23230 (23.2 KB)  TX bytes:402335 (402.3 KB)
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If the IP and the gateway are correct, maybe the problem is de DNS server. Have you tried ping to some known URL and then its IP address?

Try this:

```
ping google.com
```

And then this:

```
ping 173.194.41.232 #This is also google.
```

If only the second command works, the problem is the DNS server. Also try to make two queris, the second specifying which DNS server to use:

```
nslookup google.com
nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
```

If that is the problem, add the server manually:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried pinging known ip-addresses, with no luck.